# Installed smart switch on switch controlling multiple lights, now they invert?

Tags: smart-switch

I wonder how this could have happened. We have three lights in front of our front door, one hanging above the front door, and two on the sides. I replace the light switch with a Kasa smart switch, and now something weird is happening. When I turn the switch on, the light above the door turns ON and the two lights on the sides don't. However, when I turn the switch off the light above the door turns OFF and the two lights on the side turn ON.

What could be happening here? How would this be "inverting"?[image]

Comment: Can you upload a picture showing all the wires connected to the switch?

Comment: Yes, can you please post photos of the wiring inside the switch box?

Comment: Added photo. The switch to the right is the one that controls the 3 lights.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out! So the two wires I had in traveller - one actually controls the single light above the front door and the other controlled the two side lights. Hence when I hit the switch it alternated.

So what I did is combined both wires under one of the traveller terminals (the Kasa switch has two "holes" I guess for this reason). Now it works!

Comment: @FreeMan -- his "travelers" weren't travelers to begin with

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I bow to your far superior knowledge. Comment revoked!